# is Atom-32bit in mode protected after a reset?

Tags: microprocessors

I work on  Atom-32bit-intel, I have to port MicroC OS II, so there is no code to make any configuration on the Atom (No GDT, no LDT...):

my question is more about the state of the Atom-32bit after a reset, is the Atom in protecte mode or not ? and the most important how do i check which mode is it (which registers have to be checked nad how)?

Remark:
The CR0.PE = 1 (I checked it), is that enough to prove that the Atom is in protected mode ?

************************ UPDATE : *******************************

```
    /*Read the IDTR*/
    sidt (idt_ptr)

    /*Read the GDTR*/
    sgdt (gdt_ptr)
```

So I tried just to use IDT's address to link my ISR to the IDT :

```
fill_interrupt(ISR_Nbr,(unsigned int) isr33, 0x08, 0x8E);

static void fill_interrupt(unsigned char num, unsigned int base, unsigned short sel, unsigned char flags)
{
    unsigned short *Interrupt_Address;

    /*address = idt_ptr.base + num * 8 byte*/
    Interrupt_Address = (unsigned short *)(idt_ptr.base + num*8);

    *(Interrupt_Address) = base&0xFFFF;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = sel;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (flags>>8)&0xFF00;
    *(Interrupt_Address+1) = (base>>16)&0xFFFF;

}
```

my ISR a imple one :

```
isr33:
nop
nop
cli
push %ebp   //save the context to swith back
mov %esp,%ebp




pop %ebp //Return to the calling function
sti
ret
```

Comment: What? You don't even say what language you're porting to.

Comment: @JamWaffles : I use assembly AT&T and C language.

Comment: Ok, so which one of those are you porting to?

Comment: @JamWaffles :I am porting MicroC OS II (it is an OS) on a platforme with Atom-32bit-intel as a processsor. ------ When i checked the CR0.PE after i get in my code it was set (CR0.PE = 1) is that mean that the Atom is in protected mode ? (I did not even set up the GDT)

Comment: Right, so after struggling to get very little extra information out of you, we now know you're porting an operating system, but I still don't know what this OS is written in, and what language you're porting it to. Talk about getting blood from a stone.

Comment: @JamWaffles : :) Sorry, The OS is writing in C language, exept the low-level that is in assembly,   "and what language you're porting it to" => C language also, of course the lowlevel has to be in assembly,------ my question is more about the state of the Atom-32bit after a reset, is the Atom in protecte mode or no ? and the most important how do i check which mode is it (which registers have to be checked nad how)?

Comment: Ah right. If you could edit that into your original question so others can see it straight away, you should get some help from people who know about stuff like that - I can't be much help I'm afraid.

Comment: @JamWaffles : I changed it 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I use N450 Atom board, it has already a BIOS, the BIOS configures the board in Protected Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 9 of volume 3 of the [Intel Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) says that the reset value of `CR0` is `60000010H`.  As you can see, bit 0, aka PE, is clear.

Regardless, you can setup the descriptor tables in Protected Mode as well as in Real Mode.  You just have to be more careful about it.

---

I suggest you check if the BIOS or OS are setting this bit at a stage before you read it.

Comment: ok, I agree, After investigation I realise that the BIOS puts the Atom in Protected mode, and buils IDT/GDT... Fine. I tried to liked my ISR in IDT (See the code up after **UPDATE**), but as soon as call  my ISR (int $0x21) the code crashes !!!, Why ????

Comment: @mustapha: you're in protected mode, but you're setting up the IDT according to real mode.  Look at chapter 6 of volume 3 of the manual (it used to be chapter 5 in previous versions)

Comment: IDT in protected mode is 8bytes for each entries + LowAddress + Seg+ Flag+ HighAddress, this is exactly what I am doing in my code !!!, Could you be more specific on where it wrong ? 10x

Comment: @mustapha: you should really ask this in a separate question...  Note that `flags >> 8` is `0` because `flags` only has 8 bits to begin with.  are you sure you don't want to shift left?

Answer (score 1):

Atom is x86 instruction set, and as such, *should* be starting in real mode for compatibility.  I don't have one on hand to test with though.

Comment: I think the BIOS in the card sets up the prtected mode and builds IDT/GDT, but i tried to add my ISR in the IDT (see above) but the code crashes when i call my ISR (int $0x21)